# parsing csv file using fast-csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

```js
    var fs = require('fs');
    var csv = require('fast-csv');
    var inputFile = "SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv";
    fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                console.log('Read finished');
            })
```

my csv file :

```
 hello,1,1,forty-two,
 yellow,brown,red,orange
```

```js
fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                console.log('Read finished');
            })
```

i am using fast-csv to parse my csv file but i couldnt see any output , any help would be great

Comment: I copied your code and the sample data, and it works without any problems. Do you see any error message?

Comment: no i didnt see any errors, i am using 2.4.0

Comment: Works fine here too

Comment: I also used the `2.4.0` version. Are you sure you executed the correct file, that you saved the file, that the csv file really contains the data?

Comment: yes, it contains data.i need to parse csv file as part of my grunt task will grunt effect this?

Comment: Yes your grunt setup can be the problem, and maybe also hides the error. But the given code as you show it here is perfectly fine and has no error. So the first thing you should do is to test that code without grunt. If that works then the problem is somewhere else. And you need to show a minimal reproducible example using grunt.

Comment: try to read a file using grunt.file.read(filepath [, options]) inside grunt trask